# Cannot generate and dispaly PDF with React-PDF library

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I am trying to generate pdf of below React component

```
function DocumentPrint() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1 className="heading__main">This is a demo heading</h1>
            <div>
                <h3 className="heading__title">This is another heading</h3>
                <p className="para__text">Breakable components try to fill up the remaining space before jumping into a new page. By default, this group is composed by View, Text and Link components
Unbreakable components are indivisible, <b>therefore</b> if there isn't enough space for them they just get rendered in the following page. In this group by default we only find Image.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="unordered__list">
                <ul className="list">
                    <li>Amit</li>
                    <li>Suraj</li>
                    <li>Priya</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
const Doc = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <PDFDownloadLink 
                document={<DocumentPrint />}
                fileName="somename.pdf"
                >
                {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => 
                    loading ? <button>Loading document...</button> : <button>Download now!</button>
                
                }
            </PDFDownloadLink>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is not showing Download now button and loading is not set to false.
Error in console

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'height') at setNodeHeight